# Is there a function to combine these arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given arrays 'a1' and 'b1' how may they be combined them to produce the final array?  Basically replacing the value within 'a1' with the array data for the matching value within 'b1'.  I guess the question would be if there is a function that can do this that I'm not seeing.

```
$a1 = array('id1'=>array('a'=>'444-444',
                         'b'=>'222-222',
                         'c'=>'111-111'),
            'id2'=>array('a'=>'888-888',
                         'b'=>'666-666',
                         'c'=>'555-555')
           );

$b1 = array('222-222'=>array('first'=>array('9999',
                                            'dddd',
                                            'yyyy'),
                             'second'=>'mmgghh'
                            ),
            '666-666'=>array('first'=>array('bbbb',
                                            'cccc',
                                            '7777'),
                             'second'=>'ffffgggg'
                            )
           );
```

Desired combination:

```
array(2) {
  ["id1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "444-444"
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["222-222"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["first"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "9999"
          [1]=>
          string(4) "dddd"
          [2]=>
          string(4) "yyyy"
        }
        ["second"]=>
        string(6) "mmgghh"
      }
    }
    ["c"]=>
    string(7) "111-111"
  }
  ["id2"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "888-888"
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["666-666"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["first"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(4) "bbbb"
          [1]=>
          string(4) "cccc"
          [2]=>
          string(4) "7777"
        }
        ["second"]=>
        string(6) "ffffgggg"
      }
    }
    ["c"]=>
    string(7) "555-555"
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually what is your question? I mean you describe how this is to be done, so, what is stopping you from doing so? Where do you hit the road block?

Comment: I've tried array_merge_recursive (failed) and looping through 'b1' for each 'a1' pair, which was pretty clunky and slow.

Comment: i think there is no built-in php function to get your desired output ...

Comment: There is no built-in function for every kind of operation, sometimes you have to do the work yourself. Looping through the arrays is too slow? Well if this "simple" operation is really too slow, you might choose another programming language than PHP. How do you obtain the data? Maybe there is another way to merge the array (SQL, ...)?

Comment: I'm sure it is "simple" to someone with a lot of php array experience.  But loops usually tend to be verbose and wasteful if there are functions (or clever combinations of functions) more suited that I'm overlooking. This was my hurried attempt to ask for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($a1,function(&$value,$key,$addin){
        if(is_scalar($value) && isset($addin[$value])){
                $value = array($value=>$addin[$value]);
        }
   },$b1);
```

Comment: @Isius try without "&" before $value

Comment: `function(){}` (closures) is PHP 5.3 or higher, which came out in 2009. Codepad is still running 5.2.5. Anybody still on PHP < 5.3 is, ahum, _certainly taking a long time time to upgrade_. (you can use `create_function` to get this functionality in PHP < 5.3, but it's ugly. Do **NOT** remove the `&`, it is needed.